# Write a program to determine the maximum number of characters that can be read from the keyboard, for a specific 'fgets()' function call

Tags: c, fgets

The code block contains an 'fgets()' function. How would my program parse the code and determine the maximum length that can be read from the keyboard?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char buffer[128], whole_line = 1, *ch;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) { 
        if (whole_line) { 
            putchar('>');
        if (buffer[0]!='>') {
            putchar(' ');
        }
        }
        fputs(buffer, stdout); 
        for (ch = buffer; *ch && *ch!='\n'; ++ch); 
        whole_line = *ch == '\n';
    }
    if (!whole_line) {
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do (input output) and what is your actual problem?

Comment: Are you trying to restrict input size?

Comment: Well what I have to do is stated in title. Yes, I have also problem with understanding what they want me to do. I need program which check maximum text length writed on keyboard using fgets() function. I'm not a C programmer and also I have problem with understanding the task. Edit: maybe something like use a fgets() function to check how long text can be writted on keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int max_length = 0;
    int current_length = 0;

    char buffer[128], whole_line = 1, *ch;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) { 
     if (whole_line) { 
         putchar('>');
        if (buffer[0]!='>') {
            putchar(' ');
        }
     }
     fputs(buffer, stdout); 
     for (ch = buffer; *ch && *ch!='\n'; ++ch, ++current_length);
     whole_line = *ch == '\n';
     printf("Length: %d\n", current_length);
    
      if(max_length < current_length) {
        max_length = current_length;
        printf("Max length: %d\n", max_length);
      }
     current_length = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assigns current to max length when current text length is bigger than max. Then it outputs max to console

Comment: Thanks, I'm just gonna take this as a correct answer just because the question is strangely structured.